# Reading variables modified by pass by reference

Tags: ios, frida

Reading arguments as well as return values is pretty trivial when utilizing Frida. But is there any way to read data that is modified through pass by reference. I am attempting to read some data in an iOS application that utilizes this scenario. These are also called inout parameters in Swift. This is the piece of code in Swift:

```
var pubKey, privKey: SecKey?
let status = SecKeyGeneratePair(parameters, &pubKey, &privKey)
```

Because SecKeyGeneratePair isn’t really returning anything but rather modifying a variable by reference, I am unsure what to hook into.

Comment: If a data structure is passed by reference it is usually mutable so you can modify it in frida as you want. The only problem is that you should modify them in onLeave but they are by default only present in onEnter. AFAIR you can save them to `this.variablexyz` so that you can access them in onLeave (sorry I am not able to find a full example at the moment).

Comment: save the address when entering  dereference when leaving iirc there is an example in frida site